# Service Fabric scaling or creating service instance

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, hangfire

I am going to use Service Fabric as a task runner, tasks would be logically grouped into services (or actors, not sure), so single service/actor could implement several tasks.

There will be task scheduler (hangfire server) in separate service, from which I want to call service/actor method and wait for result. At this point I want somehow configure scaling, so in idle mode no services are being running, the same way when task scheduler need to call services - create as much as needed instances of them.

Would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are always running by default. If you want to change the number of running stateless services you can do that by changing the size of the cluster (scale in or out). You can configure auto scale (in Azure), based on performance counters, or scale manually.

A second way to change instance count, is by creating an additional service that manages those stateless services (create / delete instances).
You could scale on task-queue depth, for instance.

Comment: Is there any advantages of using actors instead of services?

Comment: Actors are not always running. After a configurable amount of time if none of the actor methods have been invoked (on a per actor id basis) then they are garbage collected. No data is lost (they are stateful services) but as soon as you invoke a method on that specific actor id again a new instance is instantiated and your state is just the same as it was before.